# mmenu - Windows Phone URL broken

Tags: mmenu

I faced a problem with the `jquery` script `"mmenu"` (http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/)
Everything is working fine my mobile layout with `iOS (6 & 7)`, the menu opens without any problem and I can navigation through the menu.
Except for Windows Phone `7.8 & 8`. What's the problem?
At the Homepage I can open the menu and the links work fine, but when I select a submenu-page and try to navigate to another site I get a `404` error.

My URL schema is (and I use the base-tag):

```
- myweb.com/start.html
- myweb.com/products.html
    - myweb.com/products/product1.html 
    - myweb.com/products/product2.html
```

The URLs working fine in WP without mmenu activated.

You can reproduce the problem with the examples given in your download.
To do so just add a folder to the examples, copy one `example-webpage`, edit the copied
html-file with the base-tag and change the submenu-urls to `"test/mytest.html"`.

The correct `url` should be (within the submenu watching the correct base-tag) `mytest.com/test/mytest2.html` but instead I get the `URL` mytest.com/test/test/mytest2.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is that:

```
window.location.href = $("#link").attr( "href" );
```

doesn't work when you're using the base-tag, because .attr() will get the exact attribute value, not a parsed url.

Try this: Open the unminified version of the plugin, go to line 1064 and change:

```
window.location.href = href;
```

into:

```
window.location.href = $t[ 0 ].href;
```

I guess that should do the trick.